# Flex Path - capturing Click event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, graph, drawing

I am working through an example for creating Arc and Wedge shapes in Flex that use the Path component to draw the stroke and fill.

http://hansmuller-flex.blogspot.com/2011/10/more-about-approximating-circular-arcs.html#comment-form

I was looking to add a click event to the Arc/Wedge, but a Path cannot have a Click event (or really any other events as its a primitive variable I think).

Is there a workaround do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I added the Path to a Group, set the group width and height to 100%, and set the mouseEnabledWhereTransparent="false" for the group. When I move over the filled path elements (there are many of these groups layered on top of one another), the mouseEvents for the correct Group's get fired.

Comment: @Marci-man - No problemo. It works pretty well. That Hans Muller post is brilliant